# Recursive variable substitution with env.subst

Tags: scons

According to the [scons documentation](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-api/SCons.Environment.SubstitutionEnvironment-class.html#subst), the `subst` method will *recursively interpolate construction variables*. However, it does not seem to be recursive:

```
e = Environment(CPPDEFINES = ["FOOBAR=${foobar}"])

e["foo"] = 1
e["bar"] = "${foo + 1}"
e["foobar"] = "$${foo + ${bar}}"

# I want this to print "foobar: 3"
print "foobar:", e.subst("${foobar}")

e.Program("test.c")
```

Prints:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
foobar: ${foo + 2}
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o test.o -c -DFOOBAR=3 test.c
gcc -o test test.o
scons: done building targets.
```

`foobar` is correctly evaluated during compilation as a part of CPPDEFINES, but not in the print statement. How can I get `subst` to fully evaluate foobar?

Comment: I'm not in a position to test it right now, and I can't find it in the docs, so I can't post a full answer, but I think the $$ is escaped down to a non-evaluated $. Try the same code, except with e["foobar"] = "${foo + ${bar}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the expression

```
e["foobar"] = "${foo + ${bar}}"
```

, as suggested by Kenny Ostrom, doesn't help either. It yields a syntax error because the `subst` method doesn't really handle nested braces too well.

The actual question is: Why do we see different outputs when using `subst` in the `SConstruct` directly, and when it gets used within a build command?

If we add

```
print "CPPDEFINES:", e.subst("$CPPDEFINES")
```

to the `SConstruct`, we see the same output `${foo + 2}` for `FOOBAR`. The difference at build time is, that the internal variable `$_CPPDEFFLAGS` is declared in terms of the `_defines` method:

```
'_CPPDEFFLAGS': '${_defines(CPPDEFPREFIX, CPPDEFINES, CPPDEFSUFFIX, __env__)}'
```

(from a `print e.Dump()`). This `_defines` method runs all variables through `subst_path` a second time, such that one can use variables in include paths, for example.

So the `subst` method is doing the right thing, you just have to evaluate again:

```
print "foobar:", e.subst(e.subst("${foobar}"))
```

to get the same output.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the _recursive_ word in the manual is just plain wrong?

Comment: Well, I'd claim it still holds for simple *textual replacement* of variables, which is probably the intended meaning of the word *interpolated* in this context. But the `eval` of single Python expressions is somewhat special... If you have ideas about making the difference more obvious, please feel free to submit a pull request for our documentation.

Comment: Sorry if that came off as rude. What I meant was that, for me, the use of _recursive_  hints that I can have arbitrary complex expressions which will get _recursively_ evaluated by `subst` until there are no more substitutions to be made. But what you say also makes sense. I guess the key here is "recursively _interpolates_".

Comment: It's all good, no offense taken. Still the offer holds, please help us to make SCons (and its documentation) better by [contributing](https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/HowToContribute).

Comment: Yeah maybe I will, Dirk :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear what dirkbaechle said; we can achieve this by
simply doing interpolation and evaluation in two separate steps (by calling subst twice). This allows us to have arbitrary complex expressions:

```
# Notice how we wrap foobar in $$
e = Environment(CPPDEFINES = ["FOOBARBAZ=$${${foobarbaz}}"])

e["foo"] = 1
e["bar"] = "($foo + 1)"
e["foobar"] = "($foo + $bar)"
e["foobarbaz"] = "($foobar + $foobar)"

print "foobarbaz after substituting once:", e.subst("$${${foobarbaz}}")
print "foobarbaz after substituting twice:", e.subst(e.subst("$${${foobarbaz}}"))

e.Program("test.c")
```

Prints:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
foobarbaz after substituting once: ${((1 + (1 + 1)) + (1 + (1 + 1)))}
foobarbaz after substituting twice: 6
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o test.o -c -DFOOBARBAZ=6 test.c
gcc -o test test.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Thanks again, dirkbaechle!